# item level permission in casl

Tags: javascript, reactjs, casl

In my case, the permission is not based on role and also there won't be one central permission object which I can put after login. The permission happens on item level. By permission happens on item level, I mean to say if I have an object of todos which has around 4 items then each item might have different permission levied as below

```
const todos = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Todo 1",
      sub: "Let's start!",
      permissions: [
        {
          action: "read",
          subject: "todo"
        },
        {
          action: "delete",
          subject: "todo"
        }
      ],
      __typename: "Todo"
    },
    { id: 2, title: "Todo 2", sub: "Let's start 2!", __typename: "Todo" },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Todo 3",
      sub: "Let's start 3!",
      permissions: [
        {
          action: "read",
          subject: "todo"
        }
      ],
      __typename: "Todo"
    },
    { id: 4, title: "Todo 4", sub: "Let's start 4!", __typename: "Todo" }
  ]
};
```

For such case, how do i handle permission using casl?

This is what I was doing

ability.js

```
import { Ability } from "@casl/ability";

export default new Ability([
  {
    action: "read",
    subject: "todo"
  },
  {
    action: "delete",
    subject: "todo"
  }
]);
```

can.js

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import { createContextualCan } from "@casl/react";

export const AbilityContext = createContext();
export const Can = createContextualCan(AbilityContext.Consumer);
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Ability } from "@casl/ability";
import { AbilityContext, Can } from "./can";

const todos = {
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "Todo 1",
      sub: "Let's start!",
      permissions: [
        {
          action: "read",
          subject: "todo"
        },
        {
          action: "delete",
          subject: "todo"
        }
      ],
      __typename: "Todo"
    },
    { id: 2, title: "Todo 2", sub: "Let's start 2!", __typename: "Todo" },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "Todo 3",
      sub: "Let's start 3!",
      permissions: [
        {
          action: "read",
          subject: "todo"
        }
      ],
      __typename: "Todo"
    },
    { id: 4, title: "Todo 4", sub: "Let's start 4!", __typename: "Todo" }
  ]
};

const Permission = () => {
  const ability = React.useContext(AbilityContext);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Permission Based System</h1>
      {todos.data.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.id}>
          <Can I="read" a="todo">
            <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
                <h1 style={{ margin: 0 }}>{todo.title}</h1>
                <h3>{todo.sub}</h3>
              </div>
              <Can I="delete" a="todo">
                <span>Delete</span>
              </Can>
            </div>
          </Can>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Permission;
```

I have created a sandbox as well

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-leaf-i968u?file=/src/permission/index.js:0-1472

Answer (score 1):

For case, when you have permissions embedded into entities, you don't need CASL. You can use it but it won't bring any benefits. Why?

1. You duplicate `subject` `Todo` in response for every todo item in an array for no purpose. You know that you requested `Todo` and even `GraphQL`s `__typename` property tells you this.
2. It requires to create an `Ability` instance per subject type (in this case `Todo`), iterate over all todos, generate an object of conditions by id (so we can later check `ability.can('read', todo)`).

All this are useless, brings additional complexity and not benefits at all.

A better structure for your case would be this:

```js
permissions: {
  canRead: true,
  canDelete: true
}
```

So, you can easily check permissions on UI - `todo.permissions.canRead`